# How to Print Variable inside loop in batch script?

Tags: shell, loops, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
set /A q=0

for /F "tokens=*"  %%E IN ('findstr /n /r "Finshed With Errors" D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\TariffUploadLog.txt') do (

set array[!q!]=%%E

set /A q=q+1


echo %%E >>D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\AllTariffsUploadStatus.txt

set test=%%E

echo %test%              ::error 


)
```

In above Script I tried to Print test in loop its Showing ECHO IS OFF.
I want to print test variable

Thanks

Comment: This ** IS NOT ** a Bash Script.  Bash is a *NIX shell not DOS/Windows.  The above is a DOS/Windows Batch File.

Answer (score 5):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A q=0
for /F "tokens=*"  %%E IN (
  'findstr /n /r "Finshed With Errors" D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\TariffUploadLog.txt'
 ) do (
  set array[!q!]=%%E
  set /A q=q+1
  echo %%E >>D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\AllTariffsUploadStatus.txt
  set test=%%E
  echo !test!
)
```

You need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to invoke `delayedexpansion` mode where `!var!` is the run-time value of `var`. `%var%` is always the `parse-time` value - that is - the value **before** the loop (or block) is run.

`ECHO %%E` would also work in this instance (as you've used in appending to `all...txt`.)

The `echo is off` report is caused by the fact that `test` has no value **when the for command is parsed** so it's executed as `echo` with no parameter, which generates an error-status report.

If you want to echo a variable that could potentially be empty, exploit a quirk in `ECHO` by using

```
ECHO(%potentiallyemptyvar%
```

Note here that the `(` is seen as part of the `echo` command - it plays no part in nesting of round brackets...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing SETLOCAL / ENDLOCAL lines..  Anytime you use a ! in a variable, you need to use SETLOCAL..  The % is used for standard batch processing.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set /A q=0
for /F "tokens=*"  %%E IN ('findstr /n /r "Finshed With Errors" D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\TariffUploadLog.txt') do (
set array[!q!]=%%E
set /A q=q+1

echo %%E >>D:\DataUploadUtil\UploadStatus\AllTariffsUploadStatus.txt
set test=%%E
echo !test!              ::error 
ENDLOCAL
)
```

Comment: Again I am getting !test! only not value of test

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is, add term "ENDLOCAL" after closing the braces.

Comment: There is no `SETLOCAL` in the code. And `endlocal` can't fix a percent expansion problem